# need split screens in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I am not a techie but using ubuntu for the last 3 years

now I have a question to ask...I am translating a book

so  I need two screens opening at the same time one opening into the pdf file from the pc other opening into the web for researching  side by side

I went thru the web but could not find an answer

help me

my ubuntu version is 12.10

Answer (score 4):

If you have a additional monitor, then you can connect it to the CPU/Laptop with a VGA cable. Then in your Ubuntu system,

- Open “**System Settings**” from “**Dash Home**” and there select
  “**Displays**”.
- If your monitor does not appear there, click on “**Detect
  Displays**”. Now you’ll see two monitors.

[image]

- According to the position of monitors on the table, arrange their
  positions on the screen by drag and drop.
- Select each monitor, enable it by “**on-off**” and change its
  resolution to its actual resolution. Also uncheck “**Mirror
  displays**” box which is for duplicating the main screen. And finally
  click on “**Apply**”.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't maximize your applications. Make them half screen-width and position the windows beside each other.